# Creating 2 non-clustered indexes with same key columns but different included columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

I have a stored procedure, borrowed from the SQL Server MCSA Training Kit which shows me Missing Indexes in my database. There are two recommendations in the result:

1. Two key columns + 2 includes
2. The same two key columns + 7 includes

My question is, is it good practice to create two non-clustered indexes with the same keys, even though they have different include columns?

and

Would it not be better to create one with all the included columns (9 columns)?

Note: The second index recommendation also includes all the fields in the first index recommendation.

Thanks

Comment: Well it depends on how to take on your performances related issue:
for example you have one most importent query which you want to perform way faster than any other query, which contain 4 or less columns and two columns in where condition. then you should keep both, because it will load fast into cache and will required less space thus less logical reads,

Comment: Interesting, I am wondering if the Execution Plan will choose the right index out of the two. For example, if it uses the common key and needs to return a column that is included in both indexes, will it choose the one with less includes or not. Partially rhetorical question bear in mind...thanks.

Comment: Well here goes, I created two indexes and the Execution plan uses the index with the fewest includes as long as I don't select a field from the included cols in the larger index. It works flawlessly. 

The cost of using the index with more includes is greater (which is logical), therefore I would say two indexes are better than one. The main downsides are going to be write speed will be probably a bit slower, and more storage is required.

Answer (score 0):

> Would it not be better to create one with all the included columns (9 columns)?

It depends on the relative size of the different columns.
Assuming your table has these 11 columns :

```
indexedCol1 int
indexedCol2 int
col1        int
col2        int
col3        varchar(1000)
col4        varchar(1000)
col5        varchar(1000)
col6        varchar(1000)
col7        varchar(1000)
col8        varchar(1000)
col9        varchar(1000)
```

An index including `col1` and `col2` will have leafs which size will be a litle more than 16bytes. You can fit around 500 index leaves per 8kb page. Retrieving 5000 rows will require 10 page reads

An index including `col1` to `col9` will have leafs wich **max** size will be a little above 7032 bytes. Let's say these varchar columns are an average 10% full. A row will have an average size of 700 bytes. You can fit 11 index leaves per 8kBytes page.
Retrieving 5000 rows will require around 450 page reads. It will be much slower.

This is an example of course. But I think it is the way to handle the question.

> For example, if it uses the common key and needs to return 
>   a column that is included in both indexes, will it choose the one with
>   less includes or not.

I would say so. But it is just a guess.

Comment: Loving this answer. The fields are either int or nvarchar less than 40 characters, however I really like your thinking about this. I am getting a bit OCD about index performance and this is very interesting. Many thanks.

PS - I'm going to test the Execution Plan later to see which one it selects out of the two indexes. Will update everyone on the results.

Answer (score -1):

> Would it not be better to create one with all the included columns (9 columns)?

It depends on queries you are planning.  For example, you have table T with one index on columns A, B, C.

The query

```
select * from T where C = ...
```

will not use this index, because there is not where-predicated on A and B columns, and C column is not the first in this index.

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned that both recommended indexes are based on queries that are being used regularly. Also, the second index recommendation also includes all the fields in the first index recommendation. Hope this helps to get a better picture of the quandary.